# Beginner issue when linking 7z LZMA SDK to dietlibc

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, libc, tcc

I'm using tcc on sabotage. I use below to link LZMA to dietlibc (the start.o and libc.a from dietlibc are in current path):

```
tcc -nostdlib start.o LzmaUtil.o Alloc.o LzFind.o LzmaEnc.o LzmaDec.o 7zFind.o 7zStream.o -L. -lc
```

Linking succeeds without any error but always segfault when run the a.out.

If I use ld from binutils, a.out can run without any problems.

If adding linker flag -static, there will be the same situation.

Anyone could advise on how to fix this? Thank you very much!

Versions:
tcc-0.9.27.tar.bz2
dietlibc-0.34.tar.xz
lzma1900.7z
sabotage-1.1.24-x86_64-desktop-1f74666.img.xz

Best regards
Sandro Yang

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Dietlibc's start.o is calling stackgap before entering main
for x86_64 by default. Everything goes well if I remove stackgap in
dietfeatures.h.

I think ld suceed because it doesn't use stack-protector by default.